# How to loop through results of Group-Object

Tags: grouping, powershell-4.0

I love what `Group-Object` can do, but I don't know how to access what it returns. 
I want to write a unique list of URLs to a file (nothing else), sorted by the highest count first.  Not even sure I need the `-AsHashTable` or `-AsString`, tried with and without.

```bsh
$urls = @() 
$urls += "http://example.com/test.aspx?a1"
$urls += "http://example.com/test.aspx?b2"
$urls += "http://example.com/test.aspx?c3"
$urls += "http://example.com/test.aspx?a1"
$urls += "http://example.com/test.aspx?b2"
$urls += "http://example.com/test.aspx?a1"
$urls += "http://example.com/test.aspx?a1"

Write-Host "Group & Count"
$urls | Group-Object
#the above is perfect, I just access to the individual fields there 

Write-Host "`n`nSummary:"

$summaryUrls = Group-Object -InputObject $urls  #| Select Name, Count | Format-Table -Auto 
$summaryUrls 

Write-Host "`n`nLoop:"
foreach ($summaryUrl in $summaryUrls) {
    Write-Host "Name=$($summaryUrl.Name) Count=$($summaryUrl.Count)"
    #could build new array here to write to file but loop isn't doing anything 
}
```

Output:

```
Group & Count

Count Name                      Group                                                                                                                                       
----- ----                      -----                                                                                                                                       
    4 http://example.com/tes... {http://example.com/test.aspx?a1, http://example.com/test.aspx?a1, http://example.com/test.aspx?a1, http://example.com/test.aspx?a1}        
    2 http://example.com/tes... {http://example.com/test.aspx?b2, http://example.com/test.aspx?b2}                                                                          
    1 http://example.com/tes... {http://example.com/test.aspx?c3}                                                                                                           


Summary:
    1 http://example.com/tes... {http://example.com/test.aspx?a1 http://example.com/test.aspx?b2 http://example.com/test.aspx?c3 http://example.com/test.aspx?a1 http://e...


Loop:
http://example.com/test.aspx?a1 http://example.com/test.aspx?b2 http://example.com/test.aspx?c3 http://example.com/test.aspx?a1 http://example.com/test.aspx?b2 http://exampl
e.com/test.aspx?a1 http://example.com/test.aspx?a1 1
```

PowerShell Version: 5.1.17763.592

Comment: Wow, i guess I do hate loosley typed languages.

Comment: After running the code myself, the other problem is that `-InputObject` behaves differently when its input is not from a pipe. There's probably some way to make it work without the pipe, but since you already have it working as a pipeline, `$summaryUrls = $urls | Group-Object` is the easy way out

Comment: @Wumpus - that should be answer not comment, thanks.  I did fix and put new results before your second comment.

Comment: Is there any doc on why input-object wouldn't work?  I always find this language powerful when you get it right, but so many twists and turns getting there.

Comment: I'd hope for an answer from someone who understands *why* it's different in a pipeline, but I'll add my incomplete answer anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-6

> **-InputObject**
>
> Specifies the objects to group. Enter a variable that contains the objects, or type a command or expression that gets the objects.
>
> When you use the **InputObject** parameter to submit a collection of objects to `Group-Object`, `Group-Object` receives one object that represents the collection. As a result, it creates a single group with that object as its member.
>
> To group the objects in a collection, pipe the objects to `Group-Object`.

So you need to use the version with the pipe in your assignment:

```
$summaryUrls = $urls | Group-Object
```